# How can I programmatically obtain both phone numbers of an Android Dual SIM phone?

Tags: android

In Android, it is possible to obtain the Line1Number:
[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

However, I am not just interested in Line1. I am interested in all phone numbers. How to obtain them programmatically?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11198055/what-does-getline1number-return-with-dual-sim-phones

Comment: Hmmm, these replies are from a few years ago. Are the replies still valid? I am afraid they are.....