# How to find out phone number of a sim given its IMEI number?

Tags: android

I have a dual sim Android phone. Using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim) I retrieve IMEI numbers of both sims.

Given the IMEI number, how can I find out the phone number of each sim?

There are methods `getDeviceIdGemini(int slotId)` and `getSimStateGemini(int slotId)` it is possible to find out the IMEI number and the state of each sims.

I'm looking for a similar method for reading the phone number of the sim.

Comment: You can't get the `MSISDN` from the SIM, since it's (normally) not even stored there, but the mapping is done on the operator side.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Can you tell me how I can find out the phone number by contacting the operator?

Comment: Well are you successful in getting 2 different IMEI numbers for Samsung Dual SIM phones? The solution you've mentioned is not working for Samsung phones.

Comment: @Rajkiran I didn't try it with Samsung phones. It works on my Alcatel One Touch SPop phone.

Comment: @Rajkiran Also, make sure that you have set the permission (`READ_PHONE_STATE` AFAIR).

Comment: Yes @DmitriPisarenko. I've done that. And the question you've raised is originally asked by me only. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using reflection, I looked at the methods of `TelephonyManager` and found this method: `int getLine1NumberGemini(int)`.

I tried to invoke it (`getLine1NumberGemini(0)` for first sim and `getLine1NumberGemini(1)` for the second). In both cases I received an empty string.

But the reason for this seems to be the inability of the phone to get the phone number of my sims:

1. `TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()` returns empty string as well.
2. When I open "Sim management" in the settings of the phone, no phone numbers are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Phone number it's not stored on sim card, it's stored on operator's servers. Look for `TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()`, this will give the unique id for each SIM.

Comment: Let's say I have 2 sims in my phone, sim A and sim B. How can I tell `TelephonyManager.getSubscriberId()` method, which sim I want the phone number for?

Comment: You can't. Officialy, Android doesn't support dual SIMs.  Unofficially, Mediatek (who made the processors in most if not all dual SIM android phones) released a set of patches to add support several years ago, but the patches are rather incomplete and only have the bare minimum of features required to make the system work.

Answer (score 2):

[Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/get-phone-number-in-android-sdk)

Basic answer-  there is no way to get your current phone number.  There's things that sometimes work, but not always and not on all carriers.

Comment: `TelephonyManager.getLine1Number()` returns the phone number for one sim only. I need to determine the phone numbers for both sims.

Comment: Read the whole thread-  there is no way to get a phone number reliably.  That's the best way to get something that sometimes works-  but may not.  Basically, you can't do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

No,

Android doesn't support dual sim devices.

See: [Detect the status of two SIM cards in a dual-SIM Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone)

as Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK.

You can contact your device manufacturer and see if they have an SDK add-on or something that allows you to access the second SIM.May be an API which can help youto get your desired result.

Although you can find out the status of the device whether it is Dual sim or not by using this link [Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim/17499889#17499889)