# how to make sure whether the telephone has two simcard in my app?

Tags: sim-card

before android 5.0,it didn't support two simcard in original android sdk,how to confirm where the phone has two simcard and get the default setting info about the simcard like "which simcard is used to send SMS default"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect the status of two SIM cards in a dual-SIM Android phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone)

Answer (score 1):

You can use SubscriptionManager to get the list of active subscriptions:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()

To get the default SMS subscription ID you can use this API in SmsManager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId()