# How to get the name of operator which is connected to internet in dual sim android phone?

Tags: android, android-networking

I have made a network monitor app. Here I have successfully implemented all the things. I have the dual sim android phone. I know how to get the name of operator. But I want to that which sim is connected to internet? I have used this code, only to show user that the device is connected through mobile data. I want to be more specific that the device is currently using which operator's internet.

```
public static String isInternetConnected (Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        // Check if wifi or mobile network is available or not. If any of them is
        // available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;
        if (wifi != null) {
            if (wifi.isConnected()) {
                return "wifi";
            }
        }
        if (mobile != null) {
            if (mobile.isConnected()) {
                return "mobile";
            }
        }
        return "none";
    }
```

Comment: did you get the solution?

Comment: @Tushar Monirul Did you find any solution??

Comment: @KishanVaghela did you find a solution?

Comment: @Tushar Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 0):

There are no API about multiple sims before API 22. You can contact your device manufacturer and check whether they have an SDK add-on to access multiple sims or not.

Since API 22, you can check for multiple SIMs using SubscriptionManager's method getActiveSubscriptionInfoList(). More details on Android Docs.

Please look [multiple sims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone). Here are some discussion about multiple, Hope this can help you for finding a way to access multiple sim network.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code https://github.com/dragos-niculescu/dualsim/blob/master/src/com/example/dualsim/TelephonyInfo.java

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
int dataNetworkTypeSIM1 = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();
int dataNetworkTypeSIM2 = 0;
try {
    dataNetworkTypeSIM1 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getNetworkTypeGemini", 0));
    dataNetworkTypeSIM2 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getNetworkTypeGemini", 1));
} catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
    try {
        dataNetworkTypeSIM1 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getDataNetworkTypeGemini", 0));
        dataNetworkTypeSIM2 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getDataNetworkTypeGemini", 1));
    } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
        try {
             dataNetworkTypeSIM1 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getDataNetworkType", 0));
             dataNetworkTypeSIM2 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getDataNetworkType", 1));
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e2) {
             try {
                  dataNetworkTypeSIM1 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getNetworkType", 0));
                  dataNetworkTypeSIM2 = Integer.parseInt(getStringOfInt(context, "getNetworkType", 1));
             } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e3) {}
        }
    }
}
```

You can get all available methods by calling:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
Method[] methods = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName()).getMethods();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by unofficially apis, below codes is worked :

```
fun getNetOperatorName(): String? {
    val manager = App.instance.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && manager.phoneCount > 1) {
        fun parseValues(raw: String?): List<String> {
            return raw?.split(",") ?: emptyList()
        }

        fun getSystemProperty(propName: String): String? {
            return try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop $propName").inputStream.use {
                    it.buffered(1024).bufferedReader().use { bf -> bf.readLine() }
                }
            } catch (ex: Exception) {
                Log.e("st-lite", "Unable to read sysprop $propName", ex)
                null
            }
        }

        try {
            val simOperatorCodes1 = getSystemProperty("gsm.operator.numeric")
            val simOperatorCodes2 = getSystemProperty("gsm.sim.operator.numeric")
            val codes1 = parseValues(simOperatorCodes1)
            val codes2 = parseValues(simOperatorCodes2)
            var simOperatorNames = getSystemProperty("gsm.operator.alpha")
            if (simOperatorNames.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                simOperatorNames = getSystemProperty("gsm.sim.operator.alpha")
            }
            val names = parseValues(simOperatorNames)
            val currSimOperator = manager.simOperator
            for (i in 0..codes1.size.coerceAtMost(codes2.size)) {
                if (codes1[i] == currSimOperator || codes2[i] == currSimOperator) {
                    return names[i]
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return manager.networkOperatorName
}
```