# Find network name of both the sims in android for pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I am able to get operator name of sim in slot 1 by using:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Is there any method to find opertor name of sim in slot 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: I have already been through this link but I have seen several apps which gives info of both the sims

Answer (score 0):

**Since API version 22 its possible**

try following code for device having os greater than android 5.2

```
List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfos = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
for(int i=0; i<subscriptionInfos.size();i++)
{
    SubscriptionInfo lsuSubscriptionInfo = subscriptionInfos.get(i);
    Log.d(TAG, "getNumber "+ lsuSubscriptionInfo.getNumber());
    Log.d(TAG, "network name : "+ lsuSubscriptionInfo.getCarrierName());
    Log.d(TAG, "getCountryIso "+ lsuSubscriptionInfo.getCountryIso());
}
```

for more information

[Multiple sim support in android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29)

Comment: I am aware of SubscriptionManager but i need for pre lollipop devices

Comment: pre lollipop it is not possible read following there is one approach which may work for some device (vendor specific) not on all. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it. But I have seen few apps which do read both sim info.

Comment: If you find solutions do let me know 

Comment: any solution guys, I am looking for the same