# How to get default sim card number android programmatically

Tags: android, dual-sim

To send sms programmatically I am using,

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(toNumber, null, text, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT_ACTION), 0), null);
```

I have coded for api >=22 like,

```
SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager=(SubscriptionManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE);

        List<SubscriptionInfo> subscriptionInfoList=subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();

        if(subscriptionInfoList!=null && subscriptionInfoList.size()>0){
           for(SubscriptionInfo info:subscriptionInfoList){

               String mobileNo=info.getNumber();

           }

        }
```

**using subscription manager I am not getting sim 2 card number using info.getNumber();. It returns empty for Samsung j5 device.**

> Another important thing is, using SubscriptionManager I am getting line 1 number correctly but empty for line 2. But at the same time when I am trying to send sms using SmsManager.getDefault() it sends sms from line 2. In that device line 2 sim card is set as default.

But based on operators available in a dual sim device toNumber (the number to send sms) will be changed. Because of this I need to know operator name or sim card number of default sim of the device set by user to the number SmsManager.getDefault(). How can I get it know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get carrier name from dual sim phone Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714656/how-to-get-carrier-name-from-dual-sim-phone-android)

Comment: in my case, I am not getting sim 2 number for marshmallow following first link. That's why I asked this

Comment: And you are using the SubscriptionManager method as outlined in that question?

Comment: updated question.

Comment: Do the other properties work; info.getCarrierName().toString(), info.getCountryIso() & info.getDataRoaming()?

Comment: if yes, how I would be sure which one is default that SmsManager.getDefault() will use? I need to know which line/sim is default set in device.

Comment: the question you are referring and mine are different. In that I might get both sim cards info but can't know which sim is default but in my question I asked to get default sim info. Default line would also be ok.

Comment: After a bit of research, the SubscriptionManager only returns a number in getNumber() depending on the stored number in your SIM settings; http://i.imgur.com/GsH04DQ.png.

Comment: So, if there is no number stored I won't be able to get it?

Comment: From my understanding, yes

Comment: suppose I got both number and all info, how can I come to know which one is default line/sim set by user? - this is what I asked actually

Comment: I am assuming in your case that SubscriptionManager.getDefaultSubscriptionId() should get the default sim. But, it sounds like you are trying to get the default SMS, so try SubscriptionManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId()

Comment: These two methods are included in api level 24. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html . What about < 24 ?

Comment: can you please remove the flag please as my question is not same as you flagged.

Comment: Sadly, I am thinking you either have to ask the user or assume it is always the first SIM for API 22 & 23. Google greatly expanded dual SIM in 24

Comment: I assumed, first one would be default, but sim 2 could also be, see my question - I mentioned it. In a big trouble ! Suggest me please that I can come out from this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132537/discussion-between-opt05-and-exigente05).

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should get it (link [**here**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager#getDefault())):

> Get the SmsManager associated with the default subscription id. The
>   instance will always be associated with the default subscription id,
>   even if the default subscription id changes.
>
> Note: For devices that support multiple active subscriptions at a
>   time, SmsManager will track the subscription set by the user as the
>   default SMS subscription. If the user has not set a default,
>   SmsManager may start an activity to kick off a subscription
>   disambiguation dialog. Most operations will not complete until the
>   user has chosen the subscription that will be associated with the
>   operation. If the user cancels the dialog without choosing a
>   subscription, one of the following will happen, depending on the
>   target SDK version of the application. For compatibility purposes, if
>   the target SDK level is <= 28, telephony will still send the SMS over
>   the first available subscription. If the target SDK level is > 28, the
>   operation will fail to complete.
>
> Note: If this method is used to perform an operation on a device that
>   has multiple active subscriptions, the user has not set a default SMS
>   subscription, and the operation is being performed while the
>   application is not in the foreground, the SMS disambiguation dialog
>   will not be shown. The result of the operation will conclude as if the
>   user cancelled the disambiguation dialog and the operation will finish
>   as outlined above, depending on the target SDK version of the calling
>   application. It is safer to use getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(int) if
>   the application will perform the operation while in the background
>   because this can cause unpredictable results, such as the operation
>   being sent over the wrong subscription or failing completely,
>   depending on the user's default SMS subscription setting.

So, the code would be:

```
    val subscriptionManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SUBSCRIPTION_SERVICE) as SubscriptionManager
    val defaultSubscriptionId = SmsManager.getDefaultSmsSubscriptionId()
    val smsManager = SmsManager.getSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(defaultSubscriptionId)?:SmsManager.getDefault()
    var defaultSubscriptionInfo: SubscriptionInfo? = subscriptionManager.getActiveSubscriptionInfo(defaultSubscriptionId)
```

Answer (score 0):

To sum everything up, it seems there may be a bug in the Samsung J5 implementation of the dual SIM on Android 23 (resulting in a blank phone number in the SIM settings).