# Is there a method to get the carrier names in both slots in a dual SIM phone?

Tags: android, dual-sim

Is there any method to get carrier names in both slots in a dual SIM Android phone? There is a method but it only detects the carrier in slot 1. To do that, I use the following code:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)
getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);    
String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Answer...
[Detect the status of two SIM cards in a dual-SIM Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone)

There is not Support the dual SIM from the SDK.

Since API 22, you can check for multiple SIMs using `SubscriptionManager`'s method `getActiveSubscriptionInfoList()`. More details on [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SubscriptionManager.html#getActiveSubscriptionInfoList%28%29).

Comment: Thanks..I go through that answer.But it gives some errors..can you put full class and where should it call...?actually I'm very newly for android.