# Android - Check for active network on Dual SIMs

Tags: android, smsmanager, dual-sim

I want to send sms using Dual Sim Mobile, make sim selection option, while sending sms.

I have vefiried this link fully:
[Android : Check whether the phone is dual SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517338/android-check-whether-the-phone-is-dual-sim)

this question is based on this question only. thats why could not type the same program now.
Note: I have detected dual sim with its state also successfully using the above mentioned link program.

My Question: i have two sim,first sim airtel( having data connection), second sim is newly(Jio 4g) bought sim( waiting for Customer Care Activation)

when i detect sim state, both showing true only.then, i want to send sms using both sims.

Here Problem is : Sim State is showing both true. But, My Second sim tower is not showing.because of waiting for activation.

**How to detect the two Sims having tower/Network having or not? This is my Problem**
I have just tried with getNetworkType() method. But, Exactly, I dont know, How to check using this code in this dual sim options..

Please anyone help me to solve this issue

Thanks Advance

Comment: Please refer this link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996197/detect-the-status-of-two-sim-cards-in-a-dual-sim-android-phone

Comment: @ harikrishnan - Did you find any solution ?