# Android: In dual Sim phone getSimCountryIso() Returns which sim?

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Friends!
According to my knowledge  getSimCountryIso () returns the ISO country code.

if I have two different country sim which sim data it returns?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I have two different country sim which sim data it returns?

Android does not support dual sim phone until Android 5.1 and therefore any extension to support it may be device and version specific.

This answered is reference from this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996639/1339473) which are mention with official documentation.