# Getting multiple imei number in all android device

Tags: android, telephonymanager, imei

I have used `java reflection` but it does not give methods for all types of device like `HUAWEI Y635-L21`.
Basically I need to get the IMEI of devices below API level 23.
Is there any way to find **multiple IMEI** numbers on a device, which will work for all types of devices?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that using "`Reflection`" is not 100% accurate. But why?

> Android does not support multiple SIMs, at least from the SDK. Device manufacturers who have created multi-SIM devices are doing so on their own. You are welcome to contact your device manufacturer and see if they have an SDK add-on or something that allows you to access the second SIM.

-[Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996639/8164116)

Answer (score 0):

getDeviceId() is the method from **Telephony manager** which provides unique IMEI for each device.

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) 
getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEI = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```